# How remove element for json file in C#

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I have json file Users.json and I want delete one element. This is the structure:

```
{
"1": {
    "Username": "1",
    "Name": "1",
    "AccessGroup": "Administrators"
},
"2": {
    "Username": "2",
    "Name": "2",
    "AccessGroup": "Supervisors"
},
"3": {
    "Username": "3",
    "Name": "3",
    "AccessGroup": "Administrators"
}
```

}

And the code:

```
public void DeleteUser(Users.User user)
    {
        String filename = USERS_PATH;

        try
        {
            if (File.Exists(filename))
            {
                var data = DeserializeFromFile<Dictionary<String, User>>(USERS_PATH);
                foreach (var item in data)
                {         
                    if (user.Username == data[item.Key].Username)
                    {
                        data.Remove(user.Username);
                        break;

                    }

                }

            }

        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("User has not deleted");
        }
    }
```

After that iteration the file is the same like before. Where do I wrong? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You are not serializing/saving it back anywhere in your code...

Comment: i don't understand why this question is downed, super useful, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few things wrong with this code:

- After loading the file into an object, the `Dictionary<string,User>` no longer corresponds to the file: if the dictionary is updated, the file isn't and vice versa, you you need to serialize the data again and save it to the file with:

  ```
  String encoded = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data);
  System.IO.File.WriteAllText(filename,encode);
  ```
- [`Dictionary.Remove`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kabs04ac%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) asks to provide a key, you can remove with the username, it's not guaranteed (especially not in your example file), that the key is the username. The result is that nothing is removed. So you should use:

  ```
  data.Remove(item.Key);
  ```

  instead of:

  ```
  data.Remove(user.Username);
  ```
- Next, you shouldn't remove data in an iterator. Although this works in this case because you do a break, in general it's a **very bad idea** to do this since most enumerators are not designed to enumerate over changing collections. In this case you can store a reference to the key to be removed:

  ```
  var torem = null;
  foreach (var item in data) {         
      if (user.Username == data[item.Key].Username) {
          torem = item.Key;
          break;
      }
  }
  if(torem != null) {
      data.Remove(torem);
  }
  ```
- You can also save some CPU cycles by using `item.Value` instead of `data[item.Key].Username` since what you do is a lookup for a value where you already have the pointer so use:

  ```
  if(user.Username == item.Value.Username)
  ```

  instead of:

  ```
  if (user.Username == data[item.Key].Username)
  ```

Comment: Thank you for the useful answer. I'll take your advice. You give me good tips for code optimization.

Answer (score 0):

You have to save the `data` to he same file.

```
File.WriteAllText(USERS_PATH, JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data));
// I don't know what JSON parser you're using, but replace it with
// whatever that library provides for serializing data/saving to file :)
```

or something like this :)

Basically you're working on an in-memory copy of what was read from file. If you want to use a JSON like a DB, you might want to write some kind of DAO/Repository that will just expose basic CRUD methods (open file -> perform changes -> write file).

Comment: Yes I've just forgotten save it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I could be wrong, but don't you have to delete an item by its key, not by a property of the item?

So:

```
data.Remove(item.Key);
```